# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Tags: spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

guys. I wanted to create Fulltext search in my Spring Boot application with the help of Hibernate Search. And I faced with such an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead. It ocuurs on line

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

Here is my code

```
@Repository
public class HibernateSearch {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional
  public List<Manual> fulltextSearching(String keyword){

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Manual.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
            .keyword()
            .onFields("name")
            .matching(keyword)
            .createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Manual.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Manual> result =  jpaQuery.getResultList();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return result;
}
```

}

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manual")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Indexed
public class Manual {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "manual_id")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "manual_name")
  @Field
  private String name;
}
```

My properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = D:\\Java

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

My Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If you need additional information to answer my question, say and I will add it. I searched for the net but still can't find the answer.
I'll be very glad if you resolve my problem.

Comment: Remove the transaction code. Spring already managed your transaction and entity manager...

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried it but when I remove transaction code the creation of luceneQuery throws NPE. org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
            .keyword()
            .onFields("name")
            .matching(keyword)
            .createQuery();That's why I'm a bit confused

Comment: Then you have a different issue but you are now competing with Spring on transactions. The solution isn't to start a transaction the solution lies elsewhere. Remove the transaction code and rewrite your question so we can help to fix the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPE while creating org.apache.lucene.search.Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328071/npe-while-creating-org-apache-lucene-search-query)

Comment: I have the same problem and I have tried to use transaction from Spring and javax, neither helps. @yrodiere - This is not about lucene, but about Spring+hibernate. Absolutely different problem.

Comment: Both questions are about Hibernate Search, but you're right, they're not the same. The two questions were created a few hours apart and from a cursory glance they looked identical, but they were not. My bad.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should get `entityManager` from `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
...
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: That's only how mine transaction is working, I wonder why!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `@Transactional` annotation from `javax.transaction package`.
Works for me.